# ffmpeg: No trailing CRLF found in HTTP header

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I'm trying to use the `-headers` command in ffmpeg, but with the following command I'm getting a `No trailing CRLF found in HTTP header` error.

```
ffmpeg -headers "$(printf '\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n\n' 'Cookie: GPS=1; PREF=f1=50000000&hl=en; VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE=YYVg5wZlZM4; YSC=nqFTzbjynHk; s_gl=1d69aac621b2f9c0a25dade722d6e24bcwIAAABVUw==' 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0' 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' 'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7' 'Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5')" -i http://localhost:8000 -v trace
```

This is the ffmpeg `-v` output (Note I've also tried with `\r\n`, `\\r\\n`, `\\n` as well instead of just `\n` still get the same error (the double incase of printf escape)

```
ffmpeg -headers "$(printf '\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n\n' 'Cookie: GPS=1; PREF=f1=50000000&hl=en; VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE=YYVg5wZlZM4; YSC=nqFTzbjynHk; s_gl=1d69aac621b2f9c0a25dade722d6e24bcwIAAABVUw==' 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0' 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' 'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7' 'Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5')" -i http://localhost:8000 -v trace
ffmpeg version 3.4.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-headers' ... matched as AVOption 'headers' with argument '
Cookie: GPS=1; PREF=f1=50000000&hl=en; VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE=YYVg5wZlZM4; YSC=nqFTzbjynHk; s_gl=1d69aac621b2f9c0a25dade722d6e24bcwIAAABVUw==
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument 'http://localhost:8000'.
Reading option '-v' ... matched as option 'v' (set logging level) with argument 'trace'.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option v (set logging level) with argument trace.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url http://localhost:8000.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: http://localhost:8000.
[NULL @ 0x556cf5231a60] Opening 'http://localhost:8000' for reading
[http @ 0x556cf5232780] Setting default whitelist 'http,https,tls,rtp,tcp,udp,crypto,httpproxy'
[http @ 0x556cf5232780] No trailing CRLF found in HTTP header.
[http @ 0x556cf5232780] request: GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Lavf/57.83.100
Accept: */*
Range: bytes=0-
Connection: close
Host: localhost:8000
Icy-MetaData: 1

Cookie: GPS=1; PREF=f1=50000000&hl=en; VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE=YYVg5wZlZM4; YSC=nqFTzbjynHk; s_gl=1d69aac621b2f9c0a25dade722d6e24bcwIAAABVUw==
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5


[http @ 0x556cf5232780] header='HTTP/1.0 200 OK'
[http @ 0x556cf5232780] http_code=200
```

Comment: What's the issue? It's a warning, not an error. ffmpeg appends the trailing CRLF on its own and proceeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comment is right:

> It's a warning, not an error. `ffmpeg` appends the trailing CRLF on its own and proceeds.

My answer explains *why* the tool cannot "see" CRLF even if you use `\r\n` in `printf`. It's because of `$()`. [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03) says [emphasis mine]:

> `$(command)`
>
> [...]
>
> The shell shall expand the command substitution by executing `command` in a subshell environment [...] and replacing the command substitution (the text of `command` plus the enclosing `$()` or backquotes) with the standard output of the command, **removing sequences of one or more <newline> characters at the end of the substitution.**

So there's no way to get a trailing `\n` from `$()`.

---

You can ask your shell to add trailing newlines, although not all shells support this. In Bash instead of

```
foo "$(printf '\n%s\r\n' 'bar')"
```

use

```
foo "$(printf '\n%s' 'bar')"$'\r\n'
```

See [*How does the leading dollar sign affect single quotes in Bash?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11966312/10765659)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found was:

```bash
ffmpeg …
    -method PUT \
    -headers "Cookie: GPS=1;"$'\r\n'
```

Or for multiple headers:

```bash
ffmpeg …
    -method PUT \
    -headers "Cookie: GPS=1;"$'\r\n'"PREF=f1=50000000"$'\r\n'
```

Comment: Weird! If I add `-headers "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.48 Safari/537.36\r\n"` it does not work!